# AVD not running, Intel HAXM is required

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have tried to run AVD in android studio but an error appeared:
intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Haxm device is not found.
Enable VT-x
I activate Intel Virtualization in bios
I installed the driver from Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager but the error still the same
Any other solution? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by following steps:
If your driver not already installed go to step 2,

1-Fully Uninstall HAXm driver from Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager path by running intelhaxm-android.exe then select remove

2-Download older version driver from this link:
https://intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-man2.software.informer.com/download/

3-Unzip the downloaded archive haxm-windows_v7_5_1.zip

4-Enter to extracted files then run intelhaxm-android.exe

5-Follow step by step by pressing next

6-Finally enjoy installing HAXM driver!!